# probability with martingales 12.2 sum of zero-mean independent variables in L^2

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

I am struggling with the following theorem from David Williams, Probability with Martingales:

**THEOREM**

Suppose that $(X_{k}:k\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence of independent random variables such that, for every $k$, $E(X_{k})=0, \sigma_{k}^2:=Var(X_{k})<\infty$.

(a) Then
$$
    \sum\sigma_{k}^2<\infty\Rightarrow\sum X_{k}\text{   converges a.s.  .}
$$

(b) If the variables $(X_{k})$ satisfies 
$$
\exists K \in [0,\infty),\forall k, \omega,\\ 
|X_{k}(\omega)|\leq K,
$$
then
$$\sum X_{k}\text{   converges a.s.}\Rightarrow\sum\sigma_{k}^2<\infty.
$$

The proof for the statement (a) is easy to understand, but I cannot get the other one. According to the proof, "since $\sum X_{n}$ converges a.s., the partial sums of $\sum X_{k}$ are a.s. bounded, and it must be the case that for some $c$, $P(T=\infty)>0$." Here $T$ is the stopping time

$$T = \inf\{r: |\sum_{k=1}^r X_k| > c\}.$$

**The problem is that I cannot find this $c$.** I know that it's trivial if its boundedness is uniform in $\Omega$, but it's not the case, is it? Can anyone figure out which $c$ meets this condition? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you edit to include the definition of $T$ for those who don't have the book available? Questions on this site should be self-contained.

Comment: Could you please provide the page of the theorem? I'm recently checking for this theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the notation from Williams, $M_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$, we know that $M_n$ is a bounded sequence almost surely since it converges almost surely.

I will write $T_n = \inf\{r : |M_r| > n\}$. Notice that we have
$$\{\sup_{r \geq 1} |M_r| < \infty\} = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \{T_n = \infty\}.$$
So if $\mathbb{P}(T_n = \infty) = 0$ for each $n$ then 
$$1 = \mathbb{P}(\sup_{r \geq 1} |M_r| < \infty) = \mathbb{P}\big(\bigcup_{n \geq 1} \{T_n = \infty\} \big) \leq \sum_n \mathbb{P}(T_n = \infty) = 0$$
which is a contradiction and hence there is an $n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(T_n = \infty) > 0$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and clarification of my question! I can fully understand the proof. It is not necessary to bound $|M_{r}|$ uniformly. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helpful :) Since this is your first question here, I just want to let you know that if you're happy my answer resolves the question, if you'd like you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that the question is marked as resolved on the site.